# Get Data from JSON file using a variable (JS/Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord.js

I was working on my discord bot when suddenly this problem occurred.

Usually, once you link a JSON file, you can get data by doing jsonFile.path to get some form of information.

I ran into a problem where I want to replace path with a variable's value.

Is there anyway that I could do this? In my case I am using a command randomly generate a number, check if that number is currently on the file, add it to the JSON file.

Comment: How are you "linking" the JSON file? Are you using any external library? How are you writing the file?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that this, I figured out. A friend showed me. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out awhile ago, and I forgot to put an answer but anyways this is how I can find information from an object path using a variable. Pretty much you can get information from a JSON object by doing the following

```
let object = {“name”: “John”}
let path = “name”;
console.log(object[path])
```